# Why is 'syntaxhighlighter' not working in Rails until I hit the refresh button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my Rails version : **Rails 4.2.1**

**this is my code :**

Gemfile

```
gem 'syntax-highlighter-rails'
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shCore
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shBrushCpp
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shCore
*= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shThemeDefault
*/
```

app/views/codebanks/show.html.erb

```
<pre class="brush: cpp">
  <%= @codebank.content %>
</pre>
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<head>

  ...

  <script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  </script>
</head>
```

In my Rails project, I installed the syntaxhighlighter gem, but it doesn't work until I hit the refresh button.

I figure the problem is related to syntaxhighliter, but I don't know why it happens.

Please help me.. I've been stuck on it for a week..

Comment: I solved this problem

I uninstalled the turbolinke gem